# Java:ImagePanel extends JPanel

Tags: java

In the belowing Java programm:

```
   //define ImagePanel through extending from JPanel
    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private ImageIcon imageIcon=new ImageIcon("pika1.jpg");
        private Image image=imageIcon.getImage();
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if(image!=null)
                g.drawImage(image,0,0,getWidth(),getHeight(),this);
        }
}
```

what is represented by "this"? How to understand its utility?

Comment: This refers to the current context object. Basically in simple words it point to the current object of your class ImagePanel

Comment: Think about that. you want to pass an argument to a method (lets call it A) of another object and the argument you want to pass is the object in which you call method A. Similarly you want to pass an object as an argument to drawImage method, and the object you want to pass is your ImagePanel.

Comment: You might take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) before.

Answer (score 1):

> `this` `keyword` refer to current class instance variable.
>   Can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly).
>   Can be passed as an argument in the method call.
>   Can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
>   Keyword can also be used to return the current class instance.